# getting single value from foreach loop

Tags: php, dom

Here is my code to get each image url from page

```
$url = "http://beta.ghar360.com";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Rather then getting all url, what if I want to get only one url?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [`item()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) method to get the first `img` tag:

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
echo $tags->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

[**Demo.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6dV68R)

Comment: Or `if("urlToLookFor" == $tag->getAttribute('src')){echo $tag->getAttribute('src');}`

Comment: @Sebastien: `Rather then getting all url, what if I want to get only one url?` -- this seems to suggest that the OP is not looking for a loop. :)

Comment: I was assuming he would use the loop provided in the question to get around the newly created page. But this is why I comment my answer instead of giving it as a new one. Yours is good, mine just provide a alternative so he can choose which one better fit is need

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `break`-function...

Comment: Break, return and GoTo are most of the time bad practices and should be avoided if possible.